# EMF generic List

Tags: java, list, generics, emf

My model contains an interface called Result. I have multiple classes that implement said interface. Now i want to add Lists of results as Results. I want to be able to create sth like:

List < ResultImplA >

, which

- can contain only the chosen Resulttype
- implements my Result interface,
- is an EObject (can be contained in Elists etc.)
- concrete Instances can be generated via EMF (DomainFactory.eINSTANCE.create...()

I tried using EMF generics, which cover 1 and 2 but i can't create them in my code. I can only use it as a superclass for other classes that specifiy the generic, but i do not want to create an additional List class for all my Results. The DomainFactory only provides me with an implementation of ResultList< Result >.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish.
You want a Class, which is an `EList` and a `Result`?
Technically this is possible and can be accomplished by extending the `BasicEList` or implementing `EList` class:

```
class ResultImpl extends BasicEList<E> implements Result
```

or

```
class ResultImpl extends MinimalEObjectImpl.Container implements EList<E>, Result
```

But this is all nonesense, either way you would need to implement a ton of methods on your own and would likely crash EMF constantly...

What you could do is: make an EClass say "`ResultList`" which has your `Result` as Super Class and add an `EReference` (name = "results", EType: `Result`, (upperbound: -1) to it. 
So you could generate a Class which is basically a Wrapper for `Results` EObjects.

Further: To make your `ResultList` 'behave' like a List, for example in loops:

```
for(Result r : aResultList)
```

you could implement the `java.lang.Iterable<Result>` Interface in your `ResultList` Class and create your own custom `java.util.Iterator<Result>` nested class in your `ResultList` Class, which provides you with the elements of your EReference directly:

Eg nested Iterator class (nested in your ResultList class):

```
private class ResultIterator implements Iterator<Result> {
        private int index = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return index < size;
        }

        @Override
        public Result next() {
            return results.get(index++);
        }
    }
```

Because you have implemented the `Iterable` Interface you need to implement the `public Iterator<Result> iterator()` Method, which simply returns your custom Iterator:

```
@Override
public Iterator<Result> iterator() {
    return new ResultIterator();
}
```

Update:
If you decided to create an EClass with a generic EType parameter and you want to create an instance of this class, there should be something like this in your factoryImpl:

```
/**
 * <!-- begin-user-doc -->
 * <!-- end-user-doc -->
* @generated
*/
public <T> ResultList<T> createResultList() {
    ResultListImpl<T> resultList = new ResultListImpl<T>();
return resultList;
}
```

so you should be able to use it like:

```
ResultList<Result> someResultList = Yourfactory.eINSTANCE.createResultList();
```

Comment: I want exactly this: "What you could do is: make an EClass say "ResultList" which has your Result as Super Class and add an EReference (name = "results", EType: Result, (upperbound: -1) to it. So you could generate a Class which is basically a Wrapper for Results EObjects." But not for Results, but generic for resulttypes, i want it to only contain one subtype of result.

Comment: I want to be able to generate them at runtime so they can only contain for example ResultA, or ResultB. Does this make sense?

Comment: kinda. You would need generics. add an "EType parameter" to your EClass, name it "T" then add an EReference of EType : T; Or if you want to keep it more flexible: simply use EObject as the reference type

Comment: This looks correct, but how do I create an instance from java code?

Comment: As in how do I create ResultList<ResultA> without creating a new class in emf?

Comment: Customizing the factory seems like the solution, will mark this as correct as soon as i implemented it.  Thank you